# <partial name="_Header"> does not render anything in razor template

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I have this _Layout.cshtml file in Shared folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Before
        <partial name="_Header">
        After
        @RenderBody()
        <partial name="_Footer">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

On the other hand, in the same folder, I have a _Header.cshtml file:

```
<div>This is the header</div>
```

When I run the .net core 7 app, the partial views are not displayed. What is wrong?